# spring xd passing file name and number of records

Tags: spring-integration, spring-xd

I  have a spring xd source  component which pulls the files from s3 and spilt line by line  since every line is a record and sink is log .Now I want to get the file name and number of record or lines  in the file (count of records in a file)and pass it as header How can I  achieve this in xd?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xmlns:int-aws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/aws"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/aws http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/aws/spring-integration-aws-1.0.xsd">

    <int:poller fixed-delay="${fixed-delay}" default="true"/>

    <bean id="credentials" class="org.springframework.integration.aws.core.BasicAWSCredentials">
        <property name="accessKey" value="${accessKey}"/>
        <property name="secretKey" value="${secretKey}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>dms-aws-s3-nonprod.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientConfiguration" class="com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration">
        <property name="proxyHost" value="${proxyHost}"/>
        <property name="proxyPort" value="${proxyPort}"/>
        <property name="preemptiveBasicProxyAuth" value="false"/>
    </bean>
<bean id="s3Operations" class="org.springframework.integration.aws.s3.core.CustomC1AmazonS3Operations">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="credentials"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="clientConfiguration"/>
    <property name="awsEndpoint" value="s3.amazonaws.com"/>
    <property name="temporaryDirectory" value="${temporaryDirectory}"/>
    <property name="awsSecurityKey"  value="${awsSecurityKey}"/>
</bean>



<!-- aws-endpoint="https://s3.amazonaws.com"  -->
<int-aws:s3-inbound-channel-adapter aws-endpoint="s3.amazonaws.com"
                                    bucket="${bucket}"
                                    s3-operations="s3Operations"
                                    credentials-ref="credentials"
                                    file-name-wildcard="${file-name-wildcard}"
                                    remote-directory="${remote-directory}"
                                    channel="splitChannel"
                                    local-directory="${local-directory}"
                                    accept-sub-folders="false"
                                    delete-source-files="true"
                                    archive-bucket="${archive-bucket}"
                                    archive-directory="${archive-directory}">
</int-aws:s3-inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:splitter input-channel="splitChannel" output-channel="output"
              expression="T(org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils).lineIterator(payload)"/>

<int:channel id="output"/>
```

and my stream

```
xd-shell>stream create feedTest16 --definition "aws-s3-source | log" --deploy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider to use [`FileSplitter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/files.html#file-splitter) on the matter. It is designed specially for such a use case:

```
<int-file:splitter input-channel="splitChannel" output-channel="output" markers="true"/>
```

The `FileSplitter.FileMarker` `END` message will contain a desired `lineCount`.

Comment: Thank you  I will try this.But  one  query how to get the filename?

Comment: `fileName` must be a `header`. I don't know what is your `<int-aws:s3-inbound-channel-adapter>`, but indeed it should support some key from S3 on the matter.

Comment: It is similar to s3 adapter to pull s3 files  which you have shared in git https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-extensions/blob/master/samples/aws-s3/  Thanks for the help